# Using a saga for controlling task queue workflow in C#

Tags: c#, nservicebus, soa, esb, masstransit

I am looking to build a distributed task system, in which agents will perform tasks according to a certain workflow

It seems like the concept of Sagas are perfect for this use case, in which there are 2 patterns:

1) Controller saga: a dedicated machine sends a command, waits for a reply, then sends the next command in the sequence, etc...

2) Routing slip saga: the steps are recorded in advance in the message itself.

I would like to get your opinion on these issues:
1) are sagas indeed perfect for this use case?
2) which one of them is preferred for this use case?
3) if only some of the machines are able to perform certain tasks: how do I make sure that none of the other agents won't pick the message up? (example: a task might be "execute this stored procedure" and I want it to only run on an agent that is dedicated for the database)

EDIT (2015-10-24): (more information about the workflow)

The workflow I'm looking for is something along this line: a 10 hours long divided into 10 chunks (mini-tasks). the dependency graph allows for some of these to happen concurrently while some of them will have to finish before next one is queued up. I plan to incorporate this workflow logic (dependencies) into the machine running the controller (=saga).
It would be optimal if I could change the workflow easily (for example: insert another task in the workflow between "step 7" and "step 8" (both of these are mini-tasks).
Each agent will run a few tasks concurrently (the exact number preferrably dictated by cpu/IO utilization) (i.e. might run step 3 of workflow #1 and step 5 of workflow #2)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 1) are sagas indeed perfect for this use case?

Perfect might be a bit much, but it's a good way to handle many workflows.

> 2) which one of them is preferred for this use case?

Your updated workflow suggests that a Saga would be a great choice for the workflow. Adding steps would require code changes and deployment, but handling long running workflows with many steps seems perfect. Also, coordinating the completion of multiple async steps before a next step is a common use case I have used sagas for.

> 3) if only some of the machines are able to perform certain tasks: how do I make sure that none of the other agents won't pick the message up?

By types. Each activity has a specific message type corresponding to the action. E.g. "`GetReportData`" (executes a stored proc?). You'll have one group of services with consumers for that message type. Only they will receive messages published with that type. If it's more complicated than that, e.g. `GetReportData` but only for Customer A's machine not Customer B's, then you get into Content Based Routing. This is generally looked poorly upon, and you might want to find another way to model your work, if possible. Content based routing is not something that is supported in MassTransit.

Comment: Hi Travis, Thank you for your comment. I am in fact experimenting with MassTransit to this end at the moment

I am basing my design on the shopping cart example that phatboyg has published about a month ago (https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ShoppingWeb) - btw, excellent examples.

I have edited my original message to include more information about the workflow.

With regards to point 3: when you say "one group of services", does that mean they will need to have separate code base than the other groups?
is it possible to have the same codebase for all of my agents and still ... continued..

Comment: ... and still have only a few of them subscribed to certain tasks while others not? one way of achieving this could be by having a consumer per dll and then deploying only the relevant dlls to the correct consumers

Comment: Sure, you could have the same code deployed everywhere but only some services register a given consumer for that bus instance. In this case, "group of services" is any logical grouping. They could all reside in a singular Windows service if you wanted. Though, it would make scaling in the future harder, so I don't recommend that if possible.

Comment: I edited my answer to add to to the saga question. While I speak from MassTransit experience, there's very little that's super specific to MassTransit at a high level. Much of it would also apply to NServiceBus.

Comment: Thanks Travis, This is of great help to us. Can you please further clarify what you meant by "... adding steps would require code changes and deployment..." this would require a change to the coordinator, which as I understand from another question I asked and answered by Chris Patterson, Automatonymous doesn't support. If there's a way I can make it happen that will be great (the business requirements dictate changes might occur in the workflow: "change the order of the workflow such that step 8 will now be the 3rd step") if not, do you have a recommendation for an alternative solution?

Comment: (the other question that I'm referring to can be found here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344293/updating-the-steps-in-saga/33345339#33345339)

Comment: You'll have to build your own coordination if you require dynamic workflows. The sagas provided with MassTransit just don't support that, per the above question. There's no work around to that.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to store my workflow inside XML, read it, and using Roslyn convert it to an Automatonymous / Saga? does that make sense to do such thing ?
(I don't have experience with Roslyn yet, so I don't know if it's possible (and if so how complex it might be))

Comment: Having a little bit of experience using Roslyn, I'd say this is possible but likely a ton of work to get right. I'm also not 100% sure you could do this with Automatonymous without some tweaking, but I bet any changes would be small. I'm guessing having your own coordination code, while a bunch of work, would be a be better solution. Continuous delivery + doing everything in code could solve the issue for less work; if you can sell that to the business.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that. We actually took a second look at Sagas with Automatonymous (without auto-generation Roslyn etc) and we figured that although we can't add new steps in-between the rigid workflow, we might be able to skip certain states in the state machine by publishing events from the Saga itself (is that ok?). but this may require exponential number of "When...Then" to support receiving any kind of event during any state. Maybe you can tell me if there is a way to do it (skip steps according to context data, or even start a saga from the middle of it)

Comment: At this point, I would take this conversation to the mailing list, it would be a bit better for a more protracted discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/masstransit-discuss

Answer (score 1):

## Orchestration

Sagas work well for orchestrations and especially long running orchestrations. I've personally worked on a setup where we had to convert all kinds of media like images, video files but also powerpoint, pdf, subtitles etc. and NServiceBus Sagas were used where it previously used was build on a polling database table that caused congestion issues.

## Controller vs Routing slip

Both controller and routing slips variations can be used. You mention that you want to change the workflow easily but did not mention if you want to easily change an already instantiated workflow. Controller types are easier to 'update' and routing slips are very good on workflows that must not change.

Routing slip carry their flow with them so the workflow can easily be radically changed without affecting existing instances. Its hard to change existing instances, controllers are the opposite, flow can be modified but need to be backwards compatible.

There are other variations too, see this post by Jimmy Bogard:
https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/05/14/saga-patterns-wrap-up/

## Changing workflow

Usually the event that creates the saga instance does the setup for the rest of the steps. This becomes part of the saga state. If the workflow is changed, then this cannot influence existing saga instances unless you explicitly want to or if you hardcode steps using if statements.

My experience with the media conversion sagas is that the workflow fetched the tasks to be executed, kept them in saga state and iterated these steps.

## Message pattern

The tasks should be a command that should be modelled as asynchronous request/response. Based on the response you execute the next step(s). Pubsub does not really work well as multiple 'workers' would receive the same 'event'.

## Task

Create a message per task. Create a consumer that knows how to process this message.

For example:

Service X knows how to process A, B and C
Service Y knows how to process D and E

## Scaling

If Service X needs additional resources then you can scale out using either a distribution pattern (MSMQ) or using competing consumer (RabbitMQ, Azure Storage Queues, etc.).

## Content Based Routing (CBR)

Avoid to have constructions like

- Service X can process A, B and C but instance 1 supports A and B and instance 2 supports C.

  - Probably better to then split it in three services.
- Services X and Y both know how to process D

  - How are you deciding to which service to send to command/request?

As mentioned, MassTransit does not support CBR and its the same for NServiceBus as CBR is often misused.

See this post by Udi Dahan:

http://udidahan.com/2011/03/20/careful-with-content-based-routing/

Comment: Ramon - Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
I'm still left with a few questions (maybe there is a recommended book?). maybe you can help me with those also (attached in following comment)
With regards to changing the workflow for existing saga instances: I would prefer they will use the 'old' workflow and only new instances will use the 'new' way

Comment: 1) Can you please further clarify:
"...Controller types are easier to 'update' and routing slips are very good on workflows that must not change."
My understanding is on the contrary: controller types aren't meant to be changed at runtime, and routing slips contain the instructions within them and thus are more 'runtime-changeable'
2) Message patterns: can't I use pub/sub and have the workers fetch from the same queue? this should give me the 'competing consumer' pattern (round-robin distribution) note: i'm using RabbitMQ

Comment: 3) Task: in my scenario I have multiple workers all knowing how to do all of the sagas, and all of the steps involved in them (I have yet tackled another requirement I have which is priorities which I'm not sure if it's possible under this current design)

Comment: Regarding controller vs routing slip. It depends on how you view it. Yes, routing slip carry their flow with them so the workflow can easily be changed without affecting existing instances. So its hard to change existing ones, controllers are the opposite but yes you cannot easility modify them as they still need to be backwards compatible.

Comment: pubsub is not the same as competing consumer. Without pubsub you can still have multiple instances read from the same queue. Just make sure that those instances are identical. Identical as in that they represent the same autonomous component.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely, but...

I'd rather go for agents pulling tasks. So each agent dequeues a task from the tasklist suitable for 'him'. The tasks should be tagged on type, so the right agent can pick it up.  Every time an agent is ready with a task, it can grabs another task. When the agent grabs a task, it will be marked as busy. (you could hold a timestamp to detect timeouts)

Comment: I edited the original question to include missing information. I understand now that it's best if I have a message type per "step" in my workflow. I am not sure what is the best way to have all my agents using the same code-base yet only some of them subscribed to certain "steps" (is there a best practice?). In addition, when you say "marked as busy" what do you mean? I would need any given worker to execute a few items at a time (the exact number based on it's resources utilization) and will probably introduce another queue for "priority tasks"