# Updating the steps in Saga

Tags: nservicebus, masstransit

I am looking for a way to change the steps in the saga, example: insert a step during the processing, preferablly during runtime

Is it possible to do using sagas?

Comment: Can you describe the business scenario - specifically what is the saga responsible for and what kind of change is being made?

Answer (score 2):

Sagas (particularly those written using Automatonymous) were not designed to handle dynamic configuration at runtime. They are a codified way to create process monitors and workflows.

If you need to dynamically modify the steps of a workflow, you could use the Courier routing slip, which is built into MassTransit. It allows an activity in the workflow to revise the itinerary, adding or removing steps (activities) as needed.

Comment: Could you point me to an example of an activity modifying the itinerary? The documentation on routing slips in MT is very limited, and I can't find an example anywhere. Thanks.